# js/jquery passing array items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Hi guys I need some help here, to my bad thinking brain :

I have an object :

```
 var ch =  [function1(), function2(), function3(), function4()];
```

function example:

```
function function1()
            { 

                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url:url,
                        dataType:"jsonp",
                        success: function(data){}
                    });
            }
```

i need to pass somehow this object here :

```
$.when(function1(), function2(), function3(), function4()).done({
  function(data1, data2, data3, data4)
});
```

of course this idea is wrong:

```
$.when(ch) -- which is wrong
```

can you help with with this?  Or Maybe it is a wrong way to do?
can you advice me ?

Thanks !

Comment: are `function1(), function2()...etc` the results of the invocation of those functions? Are they returning a [`DeferredObject`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)?

Comment: yes, all functions return a data object , I updated my example :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean to say you want to do an action when all the `Deferred` items in an array have been resolved. This is very easy using the `apply` method, which uses the members of an array as the arguments given to a function:

```
$.when.apply($, ch).done(function(data1, data2, data3, data4) {
```

See [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in the MDN docs for more information on the method. Boiled down, the first argument is the context of the call (i.e. what will be `this` inside the function; here you want to keep it as `$`, the jQuery object) and the second is an array whose members will be applied as the arguments to the function.